# Read Multiple HTML Tables from Webpage in Single Data Scraping in UIPath

Tags: rpa, uipath

I am trying to extract data from below URL using **UIPath**
https://www.marketwatch.com/tools/stockresearch/globalmarkets/intindices.asp

My requirement is to generate 5 Datatables in UiPath each one for global, Americas,.. etc from above link.

Here I am using Data scraping for 5 times to extract global, Americas,.. etc data to 5 different Data tables in **UIPath**.

Is there any easiest way to achieve this task, like doing Datascraping one time and generating 5 Datatables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Five different data tables sounds reasonable, yet the scraping wizard will generate a lot of overhead when used five times. You won't need a sequence within a sequence, and attaching the browser multiple times isn't necessary. I would create a simple `Open Browser` activity, then use the scraping wizard five times, and finally move the `ExtractData` activity into the first `Do` sequence, for example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Wolfgang Radl for your Answer. I am trying to extract data using **Extract Strctured Data** activity as u said but what are you giving for the input property **Extractmetadata** of Extract Strctured Data activity .

Comment: ExtractMetadata simply is an XML string indicating what precisely you want to extract from a given page. However, you won't have to write a Selector and populate ExtractMetadata on your own - just use the the Data Scraping wizard instead. However, as I pointed out in the answer, using it five times would create a lot of overhead. So, just cut and paste all ExtractData activities into one sequence instead.

Comment: Thanks @Wolfgang Radl.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **find children activity** which gives you all the child elements under the parent element. All you have to do is indicate the parent element under which your table is located. Then use **for each activity** to iterate through all elements. Change type of argument as **uipath.core.uielement** in for each property. Add if condition **item.get("tag").equals("TABLE")**.Then use data *scraping* and extract any table and delete all selectors inside it. In the properties pane, enter item in Element box.